# Cross origin post request from Angular get blocked by ASP Web API

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

I have my post requests from angular `$http` getting failed on IIS, so I have made connfiguration changes to allow any header, method and origin with preflight timeout to 10 minutes. Still the preflight request fails. Any idea whats happening here?

**Angular post request:**

```
     return $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: Constants.BASE_URL_WEB_API + '/urlToAction',
                data: JSON.stringify(postData),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            });
```

**On web.config Web API:**

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" /> <!-- GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS -->
    <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="600"/>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

**Requet summary - FF developer tool**

[image]

Comment: You need to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) as addition to SOP (Same Origin Policy), see this reference: http://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html.

Comment: Well initially I have added cros header using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors. and then I have commented out the attribute usage on controller level and moved to web.config. Updated question with web.config

Comment: Have you tried the same request on another browser too? Different browsers use different ways to handle security features, examine if you have trusted certificates issued by CA. Then, check `WebAPIConfig.cs` content especially for `Register` method, try using `EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "POST"));` there.

Comment: well above changes on web.config on API end does the same thing which does with `[EnableCors("*", "*", "*" )]` I guess

Comment: Have you encountered error message like `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at domain.com`? I want to know what reason lies behind the blocked request.

Answer (score 2):

It is not the problem of your frontend. 
check API configuration, and al browser whichever you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In the `WebApiConfig` class add the following:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
           config.EnableCors();


        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
       // Web API routes below
    }
```